# Problems with XSLT and apply templates

Tags: xslt

I'm going to be brief. I'm doing XSLT on the client. The output is a report/html with data. The report consists of several blocks, ie one block is one child element of root-node in the xml file.

There are n reports residing in n different xslt-files in my project and the reports can have the same block. That means if there is a problem with one block for one report and it is in n reports i have to update every n report (xslt file).

So i want to put all my blocks in templates (kind-of-a businesslayer) that i can reuse for my reports by xsl:include on the templates for those reports.

So the pseudo is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0".....?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"....>
  <xsl:include href="../../Blocks/MyBlock.xslt"/>
  <xsl:template match='/'>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


MyBlock.xslt:

<?xml version="1.0"....?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0".....>
  <xsl:template match='/root/rating'>
     HTML OUTPUT
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope someone out there understands my question. I need pointers on how to go about this, if this is one way to do it. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your idea is sound. Many libraries make use of include/import chains.  You might also want to consider using `xsl:import`, which will provide you with the ability to override any of the imported templates. Take a look at the Docbook stylesheets  http://wiki.docbook.org/DocBookXslStylesheets for reference of one stylesheet library that breaks out modules and uses includes/imports them. There doesn't seem to be a question to answer. What issues are you having?

Comment: It is often challenging to impossible to use `<xsl:include>` or `<xsl:import>` client-side, because you must be able to initially create the necessary directory structure and write the files to be included/imported -- on the client -- and this may not be allowed. Apart from this reality check, it is a good idea to organize code as a set of modules (library) that can be imported selectively.

Comment: The project resides on a usb memory which already contains folders and data. The problem don't seem to be a filesystem authorization issue since it's been working up to this point with reading from filesystem on the usb memory. Every data and xslt is stored in js-files. The problem came when i took the logic out of the xslt-report and put it another pre-created catalog "Blocks" on the usb memory. So from the xslt-report as stated above i include these modules/libraries instead.

Comment: The project is quite extensive and i'm only out for pointers. One thing i saw yesterday was that the transformation on IE client returned "null". The xml is valid and the xslt should be valid too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my experience that how am dealing this.

This is example which I modified your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:include href="../../Blocks/MyBlock.xslt"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="callingNode1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

MyBlock.xslt:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:template mode="callingNode1" match="*">  
         HTML OUTPUT  
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template mode="callingNode2" match="/root/rating">  
         HTML OUTPUT  
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here am calling the nodes based on the **mode** & **match**.